# I'm trying to find a way to check if any of the values match the sequentially remaining values in a group

Tags: r, function, dplyr, tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)

#Create a data frame with 100 rows and 3 columns
set.seed(42)

df <- data.frame(DATE = as.Date("2021-01-01") + 0:(50-1), 
ID = 1:50, 
N1 = round(rnorm(1000, mean = 1150, sd = 4)), 
N2 = round(rnorm(1000, mean = 1150, sd = 4)))


#Arrange DF and create a Match variable
df <- df %>%
 arrange(DATE, ID) %>%
 group_by(DATE, ID) %>%
 mutate(Match_N = case_when(N1 == N2 ~ N1,
                             TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
 ungroup()
```

In R I have this data structure. I want to check if the Match_N occurs, and does the same number appear in N1 or N2 sequentially below the Match_N and within the same group?

In my df, the number 1151 matches and appears on row 15 within the same group (DATE, ID).
The matched number 1146 does not appear within the same group (DATE, ID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solutionfor my problem.
I'm sure there is a better way.

```
#Create Match_true variable 
df <- df %>%
  mutate(Match_true = case_when(Match_N == N1 ~ 1,
                                  TRUE ~ 0))
#Create Match_group with cumsum
df <- df %>%
  group_by(DATE, ID) %>%
  mutate(Match_group = ID + cumsum(Match_true)) %>%
  ungroup()

#Find the match for N1 or N2 in the newly created group
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(DATE, ID, Match_group) %>%
  mutate(Search = Match_N %in% lead(N1, order_by=Match_group | lead(N2, order_by=Match_group))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

The cumulative sum is not the best for the question asked because if multiple matches are in one ID, it will only search until the next match appears. This is for my use case enough but might not be the best way for others (e.g. row 116).